# Why is my terrain not appearing in the OpenGL Window?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

When Trying to render the triangle strips to my heightmap they appear to work as the raw file is read, however I can't seem to get them to display in window. What am I doing wrong?

```
 bruteForce *b = new bruteForce();

    void render(void)
    {
        b->loadHeightField("height128.raw", 128);
        b->setScalingFactor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        b->render();
    }


    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH| GLUT_DOUBLE |GLUT_RGBA);
        glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
        glutInitWindowPosition(500, 500);

        glutCreateWindow("Hello World!");

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glutDisplayFunc(render);

        glutMainLoop();
        return 1;
    }
```

**Render call (I believe maybe I'm doing something wrong here?)**

```
void bruteForce::render() 
{
    unsigned char hcolor; //color of the height 

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glLoadIdentity();

    //loop through z axis
    for (int z = 0; z < getSize() - 1; z++)
    {
        //loop through the x axis
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for (int x = 0; x < getSize(); x++) 
        {
            //create the first point in the triangle strip
            hcolor = getHeightColor(x, z);
            glColor3ub(hcolor, hcolor, hcolor);
            glVertex3f((float)x * scaleX, getHeight(x, z), (float)z * scaleZ);

            //create the next point in the triangle strip
            hcolor = getHeightColor(x, z + 1);
            glColor3ub(hcolor, hcolor, hcolor);
            glVertex3f((float)x * scaleX, getHeight(x, z + 1), (float)(z + 1) * scaleZ);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Is anything displaying in the window? If you change your clearColor to something like (1,1,0), do you see the background change? Where are you checking for OpenGL errors? (GL does not throw exceptions. You have to poll for errors and warnings.) What happens if you try to draw a single triangle?

Comment: The window displays the correct colours as clearColor should do. Not checking for GL errors. Drawing a single triangle doesn't seem to work but making something with GL_POLYGONS earlier did?

Comment: Where do you set up your camera? By default the OpenGL camera looks in the negative Z direction and clips everything to a 2x2x2 cube centered around the origin. Do `scaleX` and `scaleZ` all correct for that?

Comment: @Botje Do I need a camera in this instance?  scaleX and scaleZ merely scale, they don't correct for that.

Comment: If you do not do anything special, your camera is on the corner of your heightmap looking outwards along the negative-Z direction instead of inwards. You should probably put it at something like (-5, 5, -5) and looking towards the origin if you want to be able to see anything.

Comment: @Botje how do i best do that?

Comment: "Not checking for OpenGL errors." Well, do that first.

Comment: [gluLookat](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml)(-5, 5, -5, 0,0,0, 0, 1, 0) says "camera at (-5, 5, -5) center at (0,0,0) up is (0,1,0)

Comment: What are the points you are drawing? As I see, you try do make a triangle (3angle) only from two (2) vertexes, maybe I am wrong. Also I would suggest to start from using glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES) instead of triangle strip. Strips and fans are for different purposes.

Comment: @armagedescu For triangle strips, you only need two vertices for each successive triangle. The input assembler uses the last vertex from the previous triangle as the first for the next triangle. \

Comment: Not super-relevant, but you should be setting your clear color *before* calling glClear

Comment: @3Dave Drawing a single triangle doesn't seem to work: So you should start from getting right a single triangle. If you have a single triangle, you don't have a previous triangle for making a strip. So you need 3 vertexes for first triangle. Get it right, and then make strips.

Comment: @user433367 also the previous question is still valid: what are exactly the vertexes you are trying to draw?

Comment: @armagedescu This isn't my question.

Comment: @3Dave sorry :) . user433367 my questions above are for you

Comment: @armagedescu triangle strips are being used as it's rendering a heightmap

Comment: @user433367 did you manage to draw a single triangle with this code?

Comment: @user433367 what are exactly the values of your vertexes used for first triangle?